# How to access 2 tables' relationship in a view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my program I have two tables/models: Users and Groups in a many-to-many relationship.

When someone is logged in, I want to expose certain links that only Users in that specific Group can access.

Now in my view if I do:

```
@using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
   var user = dbContext.Users.First(p => p.Id == SecurityContext.CurrentUser.Id);

   if (user.Groups.Count() < 1)
      Debug.WriteLine("Less than 1");                

}
```

And the list is always empty.

Is this something that view models are meant for? I need to somehow access both tables to find if a certain user is in a certain group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load related entities

```
var user = dbContext.Users.Include("Groups").First(p => p.Id == SecurityContext.CurrentUser.Id);
```

Read more about loading related entities on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)